# Will having more no of cookies will affect the performance of the site

Tags: cookies

As the title says, Will my site performance will get affected If I'm storing more cookies for one domain with larger values(say I'm utilizing allowed size for one cookie 4kb)?

I just want know how cookie affects the performance if the answer is Yes.

Comment: So I was halfway through writing an answer when I thought, 'Why on Earth would anyone need a cookie __that large__?'  Care to elaborate as to why anyone would ever set a cookie this big ever?  Because I'm just not seeing why it would make any semblance of sense.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks. I never wanted to set a big cookie. As my question says I just wanted to know how it will affect performance. I'm not really getting the reason for the down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long before me too was investigating on this after seeing the profile audit on chrome console for my web site.
[image]

```
HTTP cookies are used for a variety of reasons such as 
authentication and  personalization.Information about cookies 
is exchanged in the HTTP headers between web  servers and browsers.
It's important to keep the size of cookies as low as possible to 
minimize the impact on the user's response time.
```

For more information check "When the Cookie Crumbles" by Tenni Theurer and Patty Chi. The take-home of this research:
[Eliminate unnecessary cookies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)

1. Keep cookie sizes as low as possible to minimize the impact on the
   user response time
2. Be mindful of setting cookies at the appropriate domain level so
   other sub-domains are not affected
3. Set an Expires date appropriately. An earlier Expires date or none
   removes the cookie sooner, improving the user response time

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html